# Can I know the algorithm type?

Tags: cryptography

I have some text (original), and I have the encrypted version of this text.

Can I detect the type of the algorithm that has been used to encrypt that text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a similar [recent question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/136/58) (and its answers) on the Cryptography Stack Exchange site:

If the algorithm is any good, no, apart from some basic properties.

Your output looks like a hexadecimal encoding of the actual output - and the 48 hexadecimal characters correspond to 192 bits. Thus, it looks like your algorithm has a block size of 192 bits.

We can't derive much more information here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the block cipher modes of operation and in the block length you can get a guess. But often it is by the entropy of the ciphered text that you can get the best approximation.

Sometimes, they are even attached as metadata. A vast majority of those algorithms are open so the important piece is the key(s).

This discipline is called [Cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis)

Comment: it gives me :
5A7AFF662E217B12B7531E30A6AC538D6EE79171FCDE8F26
for the text :
123456

is there a method that i can make to know the algorithm ?